# Xcode Error - Use of undeclared identifier 'CFByteOrder' inside 'NSByteOrder' file

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, ios-simulator, core-foundation

I want to build a project on iPhone simulator

This a simple project that does not have much code, however, I am receiving an error of "Use of undeclared identifier 'CFByteOrderUnknown'"

in file:
Xcode10_2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSByteOrder.h:9:27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the file CFByteOrder.h is corrupted. So I unarchived the XCode.xip, located the CFByteOrder.h file and replaced it with the correct version of it. So it works again.

Comment: If one file is corrupt then there is a chance many others are too.  You should just replace `/Applications/Xcode.app` entirely.